# Passing JSON as a string in the body of the POST request

Tags: c#, json, parsing, swagger, endpoint

I need a small help, because I don't know how to solve the below problem.

The requirement is simple, I have to sent the JSON to the server as a string parameter. The server basing on the **key** finds the mapping, and generically parses the JSON to some objects. That means, that the payload can have a different values and structures, each key has its own mapping - different data structure, number of parameters and so on. So the payload shouldn't be parsed outside the endpoint logic.

I know, that the Swagger sees the payload as a JSON, not as a string, and it tries to parse the data. How can I send the JSON as a string parameter to the endpooint without parsing the parameter? I have to parse it inside of the application, because of the mentioned mappings.

**Example JSON:**

```
{
  "key": "test",
  "payload": "[{"IDNew":1,"NameNew":"t1","DescriptionNew":"t1d", "IntegerValueNew":1, "DecimalValueNew":123.3}]"
}
```

When I'm trying to send the data in Swagger, I'm getting the below results:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:5110/api/InboundData" -H  "accept: */*" -H  "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" -d "{  \"key\": \"test\", \"payload\": \"[{\"IDNew\":1,\"NameNew\":\"t1\",\"DescriptionNew\":\"t1d\", \"IntegerValueNew\":1, \"DecimalValueNew\":123.3}]\"}"

{
  "errors": {
    "payload": [
      "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: I. Path 'payload', line 3, position 17."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|d952c89f-4e25126d8cdf3697."
}
```

**Data model:**

```
[Required]
[JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)]
[MaxLength(100)]
public string Key { get; set; }
       
[Required]
[JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)]
public string Payload { get; set; }
```

Comment: FWIW JSON "is" a string by definition. https://www.json.org/json-en.html  based on EMCA-404 and others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error clearly suggests that your `JSON` is not correct. If we analyze the `payload` property:

```
{
  "key": "test",
  "payload": "[{"IDNew":1,"NameNew":"t1","DescriptionNew":"t1d", "IntegerValueNew":1, "DecimalValueNew":123.3}]"
}
```

It seems you are creating a `string` object which further contains a `JSON` as a `string`. Generally, when you pass an `array`, you would pass it like this.

```
{
  "key": "test",
  "payload": [
    {
      "IDNew": 1,
      "NameNew": "t1",
      "DescriptionNew": "t1d",
      "IntegerValueNew": 1,
      "DecimalValueNew": 123.3
    }
  ]
}
```

But, since value of the `payload` property is not properly escaped, which is why it is not properly able to parse it as it has unexpected characters for a `string` value.

If you strictly want to pass a JSON Array as a string object, you need to properly escape it in order to get it working. For example below is a `JSON` that contains `JSON` as a `string` with properly escaped properties:

```
{
  "key": "test",
  "payload": "[{\"IDNew\":1,\"NameNew\":\"t1\",\"DescriptionNew\":\"t1d\", \"IntegerValueNew\":1, \"DecimalValueNew\":123.3}]"
}
```

This is how you would escape your `JSON` if you strictly want to pass a `JSON` object that further contains `JSON` as `string`.

Or, perhaps, use single quote (') instead for the nested `JSON`. For example below is a `JSON` that contains `JSON` as a `string` with a single quotes for the properties:

```
{
  "key": "test",
  "payload": "[{'IDNew':1,'NameNew':'t1','DescriptionNew':'t1d', 'IntegerValueNew':1, 'DecimalValueNew':123.3}]"
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just wanted to add a suggestion that would be less confusing and would generate an accurate output for the scenario.

It would be nice if you generate the models for your intended `JSON` string and serialize the model to get a `JSON` string then do the assignment to payload property.

```
var payload = new List<payloadSample1>();
payload.Add(new payloadSample1{ IDNew = 1, NameNew = "t1", DescriptionNew = "t1d" });
var payloadStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
// payloadStr would contain your JSON as a string.
```

In `C#`, you can also generate `dynamic` type objects. Use those if your `JSON` is constantly varying and you find it hectic to create many models for many api requests.

```
var payload = new List<dynamic>();
payload.Add(new { IDNew = 1, NameNew = "t1", DescriptionNew = "t1d" });
var payloadStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
// And even then, if you have a further JSON object to send:
var payloadParent = new { key = "test", payload = payloadStr };
// send payloadParent as your json.
```

This is not the cleanest approach because of many reasons one out of those would be, when there is a change in your model, you will have to manually analyze all your dynamic objects and change all the references where you are using it. But, certainly, it will reduce the confusion behind escaping and maintaining the strings.

If you are using `JavaScript` make the `api` call, then generate a proper `JSON` object and then `stringify` it to get a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I completely forgot about the escape marks :)